# vtk file opening gets (core dumped) after building paraview with cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, vtk, paraview, qt5.7

Dear stackoverflow team,

I recently compiled paraview from source on ubuntu using the following build instructions, however I get core dumped when opening any *vtk,*exodus file.

```
#! /bin/bash
export CC=mpicc
export CXX=mpicxx
export FC=mpif90
export F77=mpif77
cmake \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/pablo/BuildParaview \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF \
-D BUILD_TESTING:BOOL=ON \
-D PARAVIEW_ENABLE_PYTHON:BOOL=ON \
-D PARAVIEW_USE_MPI:BOOL=ON \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug \
-D PARAVIEW_BUILD_QT_GUI:BOOL=ON \
-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="-O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wno-long-long -ftrapv -Wno-deprecated-declarations" \
-D PARAVIEW_ENABLE_CATALYST:BOOL=ON \
-D PARAVIEW_USE_VTKM:BOOL=ON \
-D VTK_DIR:PATH="/home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/VTK/" \
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake \
../ParaView/
make -j 1
make install
```

After installing it, and removing the "libqgtk3.so" file, paraview was able to launch, but the problem comes when trying to read any vtk or exodus file, for which I immediately get the following errors: I don't know at this point what to do. My guess is I missed some other command that requires other package to be installed?. Please any help will be gratefully appreciated.

> pablo@pabloPavia:~/BuildParaview/bin$ ./paraview [pabloPavia:14797]
>   *** Process received signal**  [pabloPavia:14797] Signal: Aborted (6) [pabloPavia:14797] Signal code:  (-6) [pabloPavia:14797] [ 0]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f54c40b7390]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 1]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f54c3d11428]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 2]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f54c3d1302a]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 3]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1(+0x3717)[0x7f54c42c6717]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 4]
>   ./paraview(ZN7vtkJson9OurReader12decodeNumberERNS0_5TokenERNS_5ValueE+0x68)[0xac31ee2]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 5]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader12decodeNumberERNS0_5TokenE+0x48)[0xac31d8a]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 6]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readValueEv+0x220)[0xac2fe5e]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 7]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readArrayERNS0_5TokenE+0x17f)[0xac31b85]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 8]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readValueEv+0x1b5)[0xac2fdf3]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [ 9]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader10readObjectERNS0_5TokenE+0x4bb)[0xac316ed]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [10]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readValueEv+0x14a)[0xac2fd88]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [11]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readArrayERNS0_5TokenE+0x17f)[0xac31b85]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [12]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader9readValueEv+0x1b5)[0xac2fdf3]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [13]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson9OurReader5parseEPKcS2_RNS_5ValueEb+0x126)[0xac2fa08]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [14]
>   ./paraview(_ZN7vtkJson13OurCharReader5parseEPKcS2_PNS_5ValueEPNSt7_cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x56)[0xac42ff8]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [15]
>   ./paraview(_ZN28vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets12vtkInternals18LoadBuiltinPresetsEv+0x18a)[0x8e9ffcc]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [16]
>   ./paraview(_ZN28vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets12vtkInternals10GetPresetsEv+0x42)[0x8e9f360]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [17]
>   ./paraview(_ZN28vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets22GetFirstPresetWithNameEPKc+0xa4)[0x8e9d3b6]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [18]
>   ./paraview(_ZN32pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidget11applyPresetEPKc+0x5c)[0x5e5411a]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [19]
>   ./paraview(_ZN32pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidgetC1EP10vtkSMProxyP18vtkSMPropertyGroupP7QWidget+0x81a)[0x5e53faa]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [20]
>   ./paraview(_ZN33pqStandardPropertyWidgetInterface28createWidgetForPropertyGroupEP10vtkSMProxyP18vtkSMPropertyGroup+0x1e0)[0x5e00e56]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [21]
>   ./paraview(_ZN13pqProxyWidget21createPropertyWidgetsERK11QStringList+0x4ae)[0x79f861a]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [22]
>   ./paraview(_ZN13pqProxyWidget13createWidgetsERK11QStringList+0x3a8)[0x79f7e7e]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [23]
>   ./paraview(_ZN13pqProxyWidget11constructorEP10vtkSMProxyRK11QStringListP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE+0x26a)[0x79f6e02]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [24]
>   ./paraview(_ZN13pqProxyWidgetC1EP10vtkSMProxyP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE+0x8f)[0x79f6a9f]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [25]
>   ./paraview(_ZN16pqColorMapEditor24setColorTransferFunctionEP10vtkSMProxy+0x22c)[0x5dc351a]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [26]
>   ./paraview(_ZN16pqColorMapEditor12updateActiveEv+0xd0)[0x5dc309c]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [27] ./paraview[0x5e2e094] [pabloPavia:14797] [28]
>   /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv+0x659)[0x7f54c62a0469]
>   [pabloPavia:14797] [29]
>   ./paraview(_ZN15pqActiveObjects21representationChangedEP20pqDataRepresentation+0x56)[0x7a77060]
>   [pabloPavia:14797]  **End of error message *** Aborted (core dumped)

**This is what I get when I run backtrace in gdb exactly after paraview aborts when opening a *.vtk file:**

```
    Thread 1 "paraview" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    0x00007ffff3b87428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
    54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x00007ffff3b87428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
    #1  0x00007ffff3b8902a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
    #2  0x00007ffff413c717 in __negvdi2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    #3  0x000000000ac31ee2 in vtkJson::OurReader::decodeNumber (this=0x163445d0, token=..., decoded=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1799
    #4  0x000000000ac31d8a in vtkJson::OurReader::decodeNumber (this=0x163445d0, token=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1780
    #5  0x000000000ac2fe5e in vtkJson::OurReader::readValue (this=0x163445d0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1337
    #6  0x000000000ac31b85 in vtkJson::OurReader::readArray (this=0x163445d0, tokenStart=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1755
    #7  0x000000000ac2fdf3 in vtkJson::OurReader::readValue (this=0x163445d0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1333
    #8  0x000000000ac316ed in vtkJson::OurReader::readObject (this=0x163445d0, tokenStart=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1718
    #9  0x000000000ac2fd88 in vtkJson::OurReader::readValue (this=0x163445d0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1329
    #10 0x000000000ac31b85 in vtkJson::OurReader::readArray (this=0x163445d0, tokenStart=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1755
    #11 0x000000000ac2fdf3 in vtkJson::OurReader::readValue (this=0x163445d0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1333
    #12 0x000000000ac2fa08 in vtkJson::OurReader::parse (this=0x163445d0, beginDoc=0x162f8690 "[\n   {\n      \"Name\" : \"KAAMS\",\n      \"IndexedColors\" : [\n         1.00,\n        
1.00,\n         1.00,
    \n         1.00,\n         0.00,\n         0.00,\n         0.00,\n         1.00,\n         0.00,\n        "..., endDoc=0x163440d5 "", root=..., collectComments=false) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview
    /ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:1288
    #13 0x000000000ac42ff8 in vtkJson::OurCharReader::parse (this=0x163445c0, beginDoc=0x162f8690 "[\n   {\n      \"Name\" : \"KAAMS\",\n      \"IndexedColors\" : [\n         1.00,\n        
1.00,\n         1
    .00,\n         1.00,\n         0.00,\n         0.00,\n         0.00,\n         1.00,\n         0.00,\n        "..., endDoc=0x163440d5 "", root=0x7fffffffb200, errs=0x7fffffffb280) at /home/pablo/BuildPara
    view/paraview/ParaView/VTK/ThirdParty/jsoncpp/vtkjsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp:2151
    #14 0x0000000008e9ffcc in vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets::vtkInternals::LoadBuiltinPresets (this=0x162f7b90) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Rendering/vtkSMTransfer
    FunctionPresets.cxx:188
    #15 0x0000000008e9f360 in vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets::vtkInternals::GetPresets (this=0x162f7b90) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Rendering/vtkSMTransferFunction
    Presets.cxx:73
    #16 0x0000000008e9d3b6 in vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets::GetFirstPresetWithName (this=0x162f7b30, name=0xd0dd8b5 "KAAMS") at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Rendering
    /vtkSMTransferFunctionPresets.cxx:267
    #17 0x0000000005e5411a in pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidget::applyPreset (this=0x162de1a0, presetName=0xd0dd8b5 "KAAMS") at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqColorAnnot
    ationsPropertyWidget.cxx:746
    #18 0x0000000005e53faa in pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidget::pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidget (this=0x162de1a0, smproxy=0x15739420, smgroup=0x15748400, parentObject=0x0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paravi
    ew/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqColorAnnotationsPropertyWidget.cxx:731
    #19 0x0000000005e00e56 in pqStandardPropertyWidgetInterface::createWidgetForPropertyGroup (this=0x11be5fd0, proxy=0x15739420, group=0x15748400) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Applicatio
    nComponents/pqStandardPropertyWidgetInterface.cxx:231
    #20 0x00000000079f861a in pqProxyWidget::createPropertyWidgets (this=0x160e2ea0, properties=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqProxyWidget.cxx:818
    #21 0x00000000079f7e7e in pqProxyWidget::createWidgets (this=0x160e2ea0, properties=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqProxyWidget.cxx:736
    #22 0x00000000079f6e02 in pqProxyWidget::constructor (this=0x160e2ea0, smproxy=0x15739420, properties=..., parentObject=0x11a63930, wflags=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components
    /pqProxyWidget.cxx:544
    #23 0x00000000079f6a9f in pqProxyWidget::pqProxyWidget (this=0x160e2ea0, smproxy=0x15739420, parentObject=0x11a63930, wflags=...) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqProxyWidget
    .cxx:497
    #24 0x0000000005dc351a in pqColorMapEditor::setColorTransferFunction (this=0x11a63930, ctf=0x15739420) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqColorMapEditor.cxx:255
    #25 0x0000000005dc309c in pqColorMapEditor::updateActive (this=0x11a63930) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqColorMapEditor.cxx:179
    #26 0x0000000005e2e094 in pqColorMapEditor::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x11a63930, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=0,
_a=0x7fffffffbed0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/ApplicationCompone
    nts/moc_pqColorMapEditor.cpp:99
    #27 0x00007ffff6116469 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #28 0x0000000007a77060 in pqActiveObjects::representationChanged (this=0x10ed18c0 <pqActiveObjects::instance()::activeObject>,
_t1=0x15732370) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/Components/moc
    _pqActiveObjects.cpp:308
    #29 0x0000000007915fd8 in pqActiveObjects::triggerSignals (this=0x10ed18c0 <pqActiveObjects::instance()::activeObject>) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqActiveObjects.cxx:127
    #30 0x0000000007917226 in pqActiveObjects::updateRepresentation (this=0x10ed18c0 <pqActiveObjects::instance()::activeObject>) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqActiveObjects.c
    xx:522
    #31 0x0000000007a76b04 in pqActiveObjects::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x10ed18c0 <pqActiveObjects::instance()::activeObject>,
_c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=17, _a=0x7fffffffc0c0) at /home/pablo/BuildP
    araview/paraview/build/Qt/Components/moc_pqActiveObjects.cpp:173
    #32 0x00007ffff6116469 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #33 0x0000000007bc031c in pqView::representationAdded (this=0x1401dad0, _t1=0x15732370) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/Core/moc_pqView.cpp:364
    #34 0x0000000007ba89a5 in pqView::onRepresentationsChanged (this=0x1401dad0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Core/pqView.cxx:339
    #35 0x0000000007bbfd21 in pqView::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x1401dad0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=21,
_a=0x7fffffffc390) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/Core/moc_pqView.cpp:199
    #36 0x00007ffff6116469 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #37 0x0000000007c1c47a in vtkQtConnection::EmitExecute (this=0x1401cf30, _t1=0x13cd7a30, _t2=33, _t3=0x0, _t4=0x0,
_t5=0x1401d210) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/VTK/GUISupport/Qt/moc_vtkQtCo
    nnection.cpp:141
    #38 0x0000000007c13aa1 in vtkQtConnection::Execute (this=0x1401cf30, caller=0x13cd7a30, e=33, call_data=0x0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/GUISupport/Qt/vtkQtConnection.cxx:72
    #39 0x0000000007c13a30 in vtkQtConnection::DoCallback (vtk_obj=0x13cd7a30, event=33, client_data=0x1401cf30, call_data=0x0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/GUISupport/Qt/vtkQtConnection
    .cxx:62
    #40 0x000000000cd96031 in vtkCallbackCommand::Execute (this=0x1401d210, caller=0x13cd7a30, event=33, callData=0x0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/Common/Core/vtkCallbackCommand.cxx:42
    #41 0x000000000cfadf03 in vtkSubjectHelper::InvokeEvent (this=0x13cae100, event=33, callData=0x0, self=0x13cd7a30) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/Common/Core/vtkObject.cxx:616
    #42 0x000000000cfae423 in vtkObject::InvokeEvent (this=0x13cd7a30, event=33, callData=0x0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/Common/Core/vtkObject.cxx:785
    #43 0x000000000cfae5ee in vtkObject::Modified (this=0x13cd7a30) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/VTK/Common/Core/vtkObject.cxx:851
    #44 0x0000000006157332 in vtkSMProperty::Modified (this=0x13cd7a30) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Core/vtkSMProperty.h:481
    #45 0x0000000008f73054 in vtkSMProxyProperty::AddProxy (this=0x13cd7a30, proxy=0x14f9a270) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Core/vtkSMProxyProperty.cxx:79
    #46 0x0000000008f412e5 in vtkSMPropertyHelper::Add (this=0x7fffffffc770, value=0x14f9a270, outputport=0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Core/vtkSMPropertyHelper.
    cxx:823
    #47 0x0000000008ec0b9f in vtkSMParaViewPipelineControllerWithRendering::Show (this=0x14f4aa40, producer=0x14e55bf0, outputPort=0, view=0x13cd6070) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/ParaViewCo
    re/ServerManager/Rendering/vtkSMParaViewPipelineControllerWithRendering.cxx:408
    #48 0x0000000008ec1906 in vtkSMParaViewPipelineControllerWithRendering::ShowInPreferredView (this=0x14f4aa40, producer=0x14e55bf0, outputPort=0, view=0x13cd6070) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/Para
    View/ParaViewCore/ServerManager/Rendering/vtkSMParaViewPipelineControllerWithRendering.cxx:559
    #49 0x0000000005e3ab4e in pqApplyBehavior::showData (this=0x119767e0, source=0x14cf5550, view=0x1401dad0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqApplyBehavior.cxx:284
    #50 0x0000000005e39fbb in pqApplyBehavior::applied (this=0x119767e0, pqproxy=0x14cf5550) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqApplyBehavior.cxx:135
    #51 0x0000000005e39eac in pqApplyBehavior::onApplied (this=0x119767e0, proxy=0x14cf5550) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/ApplicationComponents/pqApplyBehavior.cxx:107
    #52 0x0000000005ec974f in pqApplyBehavior::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x119767e0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=2,
_a=0x7fffffffcc20) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/ApplicationComponen
    ts/moc_pqApplyBehavior.cpp:83
    #53 0x00007ffff6116469 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #54 0x0000000007a82c62 in pqPropertiesPanel::applied (this=0x11a0cab0, _t1=0x14cf5550) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/Components/moc_pqPropertiesPanel.cpp:362
    #55 0x00000000079dac69 in pqPropertiesPanel::apply (this=0x11a0cab0) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/ParaView/Qt/Components/pqPropertiesPanel.cxx:821
    #56 0x0000000007a825f1 in pqPropertiesPanel::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x11a0cab0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=5,
_a=0x7fffffffce60) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Qt/Components/moc_pq
    PropertiesPanel.cpp:207
    #57 0x00007ffff6116469 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #58 0x00007ffff73ee342 in QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #59 0x00007ffff73ee544 in ?? () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #60 0x00007ffff73f00de in ?? () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #61 0x00007ffff73f022c in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #62 0x00007ffff727da58 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #63 0x00007ffff723f4bc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #64 0x00007ffff72472c3 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #65 0x00007ffff60ebeb8 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #66 0x00007ffff7245f2f in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/li
    bQt5Widgets.so.5
    #67 0x00007ffff7296ee6 in ?? () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #68 0x00007ffff729983b in ?? () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #69 0x00007ffff723f4bc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #70 0x00007ffff72468e7 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    #71 0x00007ffff60ebeb8 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #72 0x00007ffff6a6b310 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
    #73 0x00007ffff6a6d105 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
    #74 0x00007ffff6a48d7b in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
    #75 0x00007fffecda0f40 in ?? () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
    #76 0x00007ffff123b197 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    #77 0x00007ffff123b3f0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    #78 0x00007ffff123b49c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
    #79 0x00007ffff613e11f in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #80 0x00007ffff60ea4aa in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #81 0x00007ffff60f2d34 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /home/pablo/BuildParaview/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
    #82 0x0000000005db6db3 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdbf8) at /home/pablo/BuildParaview/paraview/build/Applications/ParaView/paraview_main.cxx:121
```

Comment: since you built it in debug, can you run paraview with gdb and provide a backtrace ?

Comment: I added the backtrace in my question above, thanks

Comment: which version of ParaView are you building ? on which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Paraview 5.5 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I suspect your use of `-ftrapv` may be catching a problem in the JSON parser. Maybe try to remove that compiler option and see that gets you past this error?

Comment: It Worked!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed -ftrapv from compile flags